# Sources on why the variance of the mean of two sampled variables from the same population is lesser than the variance of their population

Tags: variance, random-variable

If I generate in R:

```r
set.seed(1)
x1<-rnorm(n=1000000, mean=0, sd=1)
x2<-rnorm(n=1000000, mean=0, sd=1)
x.bar <- (x1 + x2) / 2

var(x1)
var(x.bar)
```

It confirms that, given $X$ being a r.v. $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_*$ being its random sample made of $n \rightarrow \infty$ elements uniformly drawn,

$s^2 (\frac{\sum^{2}{X_*}}{2}) \sim \frac{Var(X)}{2}$

One can computationally verify that, given any $i$, and finite $Var(X)$ it holds the generalization:

$s^2 (\frac{\sum^{i} {X_*}}{i}) \sim \frac{Var(X)}{i}$, where

$* : (1,2,...,i)$

hence

$i \in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow s^2 (\frac{\sum^i{X_*}}{i}) < Var(X)$

First of all, I would like a source that confirms this analitically.

Also, I would like a source that confirms this extension:

$i \in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow s^2 (\sum^i {X_* \cdot p_*}) < Var(X)$,

with $\sum{p_*} = 1$ and $p_* \in (0,1), \forall p_*$

Comment: Your notation is nonstandard: could you define it?  In particular, what do "$s^2$" and "$\Sigma^2$" mean?  Please notice that the most obvious attempt at interpreting the latter is $\Sigma^2 X = \sum_{i=1}^2 X = 2X,$ but in that case your results are false.  It is likely you are assuming an infinite sequence of identically, independently distributed variables $X_i.$

Comment: $s^2$ is sample variance. I omitted the subscript in the sums and in the $X$, yes. I will figure out how to increase clarity, since I realised that $X_i$ is conceptually wrong. $i$ is the number of samples. I am not assuming an infinite set of variables (I did not set parameterisation for $i$), $X$ is always the same population, $X_*$ are its arbitrarily large samples.

Comment: If you are trying to make a general statement about arbitrarily large samples, then you need an infinite sequence of $X_i$ -- because no finite sequence is arbitrarily large, that is exactly the same thing as an arbitrarily large sequence of $X_i.$

Comment: I can only add to clarify is that the sum $\sum{X_*}$ is vectorial (horizontal) not scalar. I assumed that sums of sampled variables is by default vectorial. I don't really care about the size of $n$, assuming $n$ to be sufficiently large while $i$ should be each $\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Calling $s^2$ a "sample variance" is inconsistent with your notation, because the argument of $s^2$ is a *single random variable* (namely, whatever you might mean by "$\sum^2 X/2$").  This is not just a minor issue: it raises concerns about exactly what you are trying to demonstrate.  Moreover, it's vague: there are at least two different but standard definitions of "sample variance" and several more meanings are plausible in this context.  Please either use standard mathematical and statistical notation or clearly define your symbols and terms.

Comment: $\frac{\sum^2{X}}{2}$ is, indeed, a single random variable. Singular random variables have a sample variance across their values, and a population variance ($Var$) as a parameter. If one checks the Wikipedia notation for "sample variance", is $s^2$, indeed. There is distinction between biased and unbiased (imo trivial given $n \rightarrow \infty$) but the notation is that one.

I requested mostly sources, you can be helpful providing sources.

Comment: It seems(\*) that all the properties you are asking about follow from the fact that $Var(aX+bY) = a^2Var(x) + b^2Var(Y)$ (\* can't be entirely sure because your notation is very confused)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Comment: We need to know what your question really is before it's worthwhile attempting any kind of answer.